# On delete cascade with TOP never returns

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, query-optimization, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

In Azure SQL I have the following tables: orders (small) -- shipments (bigger) -- destinations (huge)

```
create table orders
(
  id                        bigint    not null,
  constraint order_pk primary key (id),
  delivery_date             date      not null,
  latest                    bit       not null,
  created_on                datetime2 not null,
)
create index orders_house_keeping_idx on orders(created_on, latest);

create table shipments
(
  id               bigint    not null,
  constraint shipment_pk primary key (id),
  order_id         bigint    not null,
  constraint shipment_parent_order_fk foreign key (order_id) references orders (id),
  delivery_runtime tinyint   not null,
  created_on       datetime2 not null,
)
alter table shipments
  add constraint shipment_parent_order_fk foreign key (order_id) references orders (id) on delete cascade;
create index shipments_order_id_fk_idx on shipments (order_id, delivery_runtime);

create table destinations
(
  id             bigint       not null,
  constraint destination_pk primary key (id),
  order_id         bigint    not null,
  prefix         varchar(255) not null,
  shipment_id    bigint       not null,
  constraint destination_parent_shipment_fk foreign key (shipment_id) references shipments (id),
  created_on     datetime2    not null,
)
alter table destinations
  add constraint destination_parent_shipment_fk foreign key (shipment_id) references shipments (id) on delete cascade;
alter table destinations
  add constraint destination_order_id_fk foreign key (order_id) references orders (id);
create index destinations_order_id_fk_idx on destinations(order_id)
```

If I execute the following delete (cascaded)

```
delete top(2) o from orders o         
where o.created_on < '2023-08-25' and o.latest = 0
```

the query returns within the following times:

```
delete top(1) o from kfc.orders o ..... always 5 seconds to execute
delete top(2) o from kfc.orders o ..... always 5 seconds to execute
delete top(3) o from kfc.orders o ..... query never returns?!
delete top(4), top(5), top(6) ..... query never returns?!
```

What happens here?! Why top(3+) never returns?

- There is no relevant cpu, ram, dataIO change visible on the db server
- Playing around with the OPTION (MAXDOP 0)  has no effect
- I don't even get a query execution plan for a top(3+) query

For a o.latest = 1 query, the execution returns immediately for top(29) but fails to return vor top(30+) ?

```
delete top(29) o from orders o        
where o.created_on < '2023-08-25' and o.latest = 1
```

Comment: You can tell us better than we can. "Never returns" usually means blocking, not a slower query. When you have a scenario like this, check `sys.dm_exec_requests` for blocking (`blocking_session_id`) and if nothing there then figure out what it is waiting on (`sys.dm_exec_session_waits_stats`). As an aside, most seasoned folks in the SQL Server space almost unilaterally discard cascade as an option.

Comment: Typo in above: `wait_stats` not `waits_stats`.

Comment: I've *assumed* by "Azure SQL" you mean [[tag:azure-sql-database]]. if you mean a different azure product, such as [[tag:azure-synapse]], [[tag:azure-sql-edge]], [[tag:azure-sql-managed-instance]], etc, then please [edit] your question to correct the tag(s).

Comment: Thank you @AaronBertrand Yes, sys.dm_exec_requests shows my request with: status=suspended, blocking_session_id=0, wait_type=PAGEIOLATCH_SH. Let#s see what i can do with that..

Comment: And what about `sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats`? `sys.dm_exec_requests` just shows _right now_, while the other shows waits accumulated for the life of the session.